# Using field in Trunc's kind property

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-postgresql

I use PostgreSQL in my project and have three related models:

```py
class Timer(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
    task = models.ForeignKey(
        Task,
        models.CASCADE,
        related_name="timers",
    )

class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    wanted_duration = models.DurationField()
    frequency = models.ForeignKey(
        Frequency,
        models.CASCADE,
        related_name="tasks",
    )


class Frequency(models.Model):
    class TimeUnitChoices(models.TextChoices):
        DAY = "day", "day"
        WEEK = "week", "week"
        MONTH = "month", "month"
        QUARTER = "quarter", "quarter"
        YEAR = "year", "year"

    events_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    time_unit = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=TimeUnitChoices.choices
    )
```

I want to get a start of timespan (day, week - a value of Frequency's **time_unit**) according to **start** date (field of Timer).

I tried execute next code: `task.timers.annotate(start_of=Trunc('start', kind='task__frequency__time_unit'))`

But Django doesn't accept field in **kind** argument of Trunc class. Error: `psycopg.ProgrammingError: cannot adapt type 'F' using placeholder '%t' (format: TEXT)`

If I execute a following query in raw SQL:

```sql
SELECT
DATE_TRUNC(schedules_frequency.time_unit, timers_timer.start)::date as start_of
FROM public.tasks_task
INNER JOIN public.schedules_frequency ON tasks_task.frequency_id = schedules_frequency.id
INNER JOIN public.timers_timer ON timers_timer.task_id = tasks_task.id;
```

Everything works as wanted. Is there workaround without using raw SQL directly in the Django project?

Comment: This will not work, the `kind` is interpreted at Python level: https://github.com/django/django/blob/59f475470494ce5b8cbff816b1e5dafcbd10a3a3/django/db/backends/mysql/operations.py#L113-L136 it thus needs to be known when *constructing* the query, not at the database level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works:

```
class MyTrunc(Func):
    def as_postgresql(self, compiler, connection):
        return super().as_sql(compiler, connection, function="DATE_TRUNC")
```

But calling this function demand to swap kind with date when passing them:

```
task.timers.annotate(start_of=Trunc('task__frequency__time_unit', 'start'))
```

**I'm not sure if this implementation is vulnerable to SQL injection**

Answer (score 1):

This will not work. Indeed, Django will check the value of `kind` when it *constructs* the query, and then depending on the kind, make a different query, as we can see in the [source code for *MySQL* <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/59f475470494ce5b8cbff816b1e5dafcbd10a3a3/django/db/backends/mysql/operations.py#L113-L136):

> ```
> def datetime_trunc_sql(self, lookup_type, sql, params, tzname):
>     sql, params = self._convert_sql_to_tz(sql, params, tzname)
>     fields = ["year", "month", "day", "hour", "minute", "second"]
>     format = ("%Y-", "%m", "-%d", " %H:", "%i", ":%s")
>     format_def = ("0000-", "01", "-01", " 00:", "00", ":00")
>     if lookup_type == "quarter":
>         return (
>             f"CAST(DATE_FORMAT(MAKEDATE(YEAR({sql}), 1) + "
>             f"INTERVAL QUARTER({sql}) QUARTER - "
>             f"INTERVAL 1 QUARTER, %s) AS DATETIME)"
>         ), (*params, *params, "%Y-%m-01 00:00:00")
>     if lookup_type == "week":
>         return (
>             f"CAST(DATE_FORMAT("
>             f"DATE_SUB({sql}, INTERVAL WEEKDAY({sql}) DAY), %s) AS DATETIME)"
>         ), (*params, *params, "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00")
>     try:
>         i = fields.index(lookup_type) + 1
>     except ValueError:
>         pass
>     else:
>         format_str = "".join(format[:i] + format_def[i:])
>         return f"CAST(DATE_FORMAT({sql}, %s) AS DATETIME)", (*params, format_str)
>     return sql, params
> ```

but for other backends, like [*Oracle* <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/59f475470494ce5b8cbff816b1e5dafcbd10a3a3/django/db/backends/oracle/operations.py#L83-L105), it is similar.

You can make a function that works for a *specific dialect*:

```
from django.db.models.expression import Func


class CustomDateTrunc(Func):
    function = 'DATE_TRUNC'
```

then we can work with:

```
from django.db.models import DateField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

task.timers.annotate(
    start_of=Cast(
        CustomDateTrunc('start', kind='task__frequency__time_unit'),
        output_field=DateField(),
    )
)
```

but that will only work for some *specific* dialects, which is unfortunately not really the intention of the Django ORM.

Comment: Maybe we can achieve this in SQLAlchemy